# Sails.js model - create associations to self?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Using sails.js v0.10.0-rc7, I would like to save a user and his friends.

I guess I need to somehow create a many-to-many association from a model to itself? Is it possible?

User.js:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        friends: {
            collection: 'user',
            via: ?
        }
    }
};
```

I'm using sails-mysql if it matters.
I found this question, which is relevant but didn't solve my problem: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/410

Thanks!

Update:
So far I found two ways of doing this, but both uses redundant data:

### Option 1

As suggested by hansmei:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id:{
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    friends: {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'id'
    }
  }
}
```

Which requires me to save each friendship twice:

```
User.findOne(1).exec(function (err, user) {
    user.friends.add(2);
...
User.findOne(2).exec(function (err, user) {
    user.friends.add(1);
...
```

### Option 2

```
attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    friends: {
        collection: 'user',
        via: 'friendOf',
        dominant: true
    },
    friendOf:{
        collection:'user',
        via:'friends'
    }
}
```

Which is also redundant, because friendship is always mutual.
(If user A is friend of user B, then user B must be a friend of user A)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to make associations to self in this way (at least for local disk storage). It should work for MySQL as well.

User model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id:{
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    friends: {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'id'
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's a valid many-to-many relationship, but I think you can tweak it to make it work for you:)

Comment: Thanks,
If I do it that way, I will have to save each friendship twice, for example:
    User.findOne(1)
        user.friends.add(2);
    User.findOne(2)
        user.friends.add(1);

Comment: I'll check it out further. Give me a few days:)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't find a better solution. It all boils down to how you best define a friendship: database-wise. I believe storing each friendship twice is the best way to go. Let me know if you come up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I wanted to solve in my [Backbone.Sails](https://github.com/iahag001/Backbone.Sails) plugin (until Waterline sorts it out).

I have completely rewritten the Sails blueprints, including support for self referencing many to many associations. In the model definition, you simply need to adopt the conventions required:

**/api/models/Person.coffee**

```
module.exports =
    attributes:
        friends:
            collection: "person"
            via: "_friends"
            dominant: true
        _friends:
            collection: "person"
            via: "friends"
```

Above, the `friends` attribute is the collection to be persisted. When persisting via the [blueprints](https://github.com/iahag001/Backbone.Sails/tree/master/api/blueprints), the `_friends` collection will mirror that of the `friends` collection, mimicing any add or remove requests made - which means the `friends` collection will be a mutual relation without any extra code needed client side.

You can download the blueprints [here](https://github.com/iahag001/Backbone.Sails/tree/master/api/blueprints). They'll work fine without the front-end part of this plugin (though you will need to compile them or `npm install coffee-script`). Just include them in your **/api/blueprints** folder and sails (0.10) will pick them up.

*Whilst I appreciate this solution is far from ideal, it seems to be the best one for the time being (especially if you use blueprints for all your persistence). A better workaround would be the life-cycle callbacks - but they don't apply to the `.add(id)` and `.remove(id)` functions.*